# Android messed up drawables

Tags: java, android, eclipse, drawable

There is something very strange happening in my app. only happens on one phone.
In every view appears a drawable on top, that won't disappear, and that drawable dosn't exist on that screen. I've done few things;

- Project > clean
- Check my drawable names
- Restart eclipse

My app screenshot (WRONG):

[image]

My app screenshot (How it should be):

[image]

Comment: background of every TextView is shown as arrow.

Comment: There isn't any background, view, set with the arrow in this window

Comment: post your Activity XML and also Drawable XML(if you have)

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded Eclipse version and run ./eclipse -clean, and now everything is perfect :-D

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your styles.xml and check if you aren't putting any drawable on every view, overriding any android style.

Additionally, try Hierarchy View and check exactly which resource is being drawed in the strange views. You will probably get the ID of the resource, with that, search in you R for the ID and try to narrow down which drawable if annoying you.

Answer (score 0):

- check your images - where do you have these arrows
- search for names of these files in the project

Answer (score 0):

Check which kind of device throws this error and check whether you have written any specific layout for that particular screen size and density. If so, check whether you have added some image by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use uiautomatorviewer tool to detect the exact error